# mitmproxy: Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, pip, cryptography, mitmproxy

```
Building wheels for collected packages: cryptography
  Building wheel for cryptography (PEP 517) ... error
......
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

When I use pip to install mitmproxy, it always gives me the same error, the computer has cryptography version 3.1.1 installed!

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3? What OS? Are you sure cryptography is installed in the same virtual environment you are currently working on?

Comment: I have fixed a similar issue by recreating the virtual env